# How to avoid AJAX caching in Internet Explorer 11 when additional query string parameters or using POST are not an option

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, caching

I realize this question has been asked, but in modern REST practice none of the previous iterations of this question nor their answers are accurate or sufficient.  A definitive answer to this question is needed.

The problem is well known, IE (even 11) caches AJAX requests, which is really really dumb.  Everyone understands this.

What is *not* well understood is that none of the previous answers are sufficient.  Every previous instance of this question on SO is marked as sufficiently answered by either:

1) Using a unique query string parameter (such as a unix timestamp) on each request, so as to make each request URL unique, thereby preventing caching.

-- or --

2) using POST instead of GET, as IE does not cache POST requests except in certain unique circumstances.

-- or --

3) using 'cache-control' headers passed by the server.

IMO in *many* situations involving modern REST API practice, none of these answers are sufficient or practical.  A REST API will have completely different handlers for POST and GET requests, with completely different behavior, so POST is typically not an appropriate or correct alternative to GET.  As well, many APIs have strict validation around them, and for numerous reasons, will generate 500 or 400 errors when fed query string parameters that they aren't expecting.  Lastly, often we are interfacing with 3rd-party or otherwise inflexible REST APIs where we do not have control over the headers provided by the server response, and adding cache control headers is not within our power.

So, the question is:

Is there really nothing that can be done on the client-side in this situation to prevent I.E. from caching the results of an AJAX GET request?

Comment: by best practice, do you mean a solution? the "best practice" is probably to use one of the things you specifically noted you don't want to use.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that IE would really require these often impractical means

Comment: If IE ignores the cache control headers, there's nothing else you can use other that what you listed.

Comment: To be clear though, other browsers cache Ajax requests too, not just IE.

Comment: Kevin B which?  I've never seen this behavior in another (commonly) used browser

Comment: The difference is IE will cache it unless you tell it not to, and in some cases even then it will.

Comment: Using POST is a bad idea. For one thing, that means you can't use POST for POSTing data because you are using for GET. But also, it would mean being unable to apply global rules to methods, such as requiring validation tokens for all POST requests.

Answer (score 60):

Caching is normally controlled through setting headers on the content when it is returned by the server. If you're already doing that and IE is ignoring them and caching anyway, the only way to get around it would be to use one of the cache busting techniques mentioned in your question. In the case of an API, it would likely be better to make sure you are using proper cache headers before attempting any of the cache busting techniques.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching_FAQ

```
Cache-control: no-cache
Cache-control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
```

Comment: Appreciate the honest attempt at an answer, but I fear this leaves us in "duplicate question/answer" territory.  Oh well.  I bet this question will get downvoted, I will delete, and collect my "peer-pressure" badge ;).

Comment: As per your question, you mention "modern REST API". While I do agree that using the "wrong" http verb or a useless parameter are hacky solutions, and should not work for clean and nice implementations, the actual designed (thus, preferred) way of setting cache controls is server-side with the HTTP headers mentioned in this answer.

Comment: @stolli so much for that peer pressure badge.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't control the API, you might be able to disable IE caching by adding request headers on the ajax gets:

```
'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Expires': '0'
```