# Angular: attr.class on svg doesn't work with IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer, svg, attributes

I want to indicate if a user favorited a certain element or not.

The svg has a class for basic styling: `favoritesStar`. If the user favorited the element, there should be a second class: `favoritesStarActive`.

```
<div class="favoriteStarWrapper">
    <svg [ngClass]="getFavoriteStarClasses(project)" viewBox="0 0 99.109 94.258" enable-background="new 0 0 99.109 94.258" xml:space="preserve">
        <polygon points="49.555,0 64.868,31.028 99.109,36.003 74.333,60.155 80.181,94.258 49.555,78.156 18.928,94.258 24.777,60.155 0,36.003 34.241,31.028 " />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Usually we use a normal `class="favoritesStar"` and `[class.favoritesStarActive]="project.IsUserFavorite"`. `project` is async by the way.

Because of some certain problems with IE, there's a bug. [See this discussion](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6327).

There's a fix linked. I tried it with the following counterpart for the upper html:

```
private getFavoriteStarClasses(project: Project) {
    let classes = "favoritesStar";
    if (project.IsUserFavorite) {
        classes = classes + " favoritesStarActive";
    }

    return classes;
}
```

Strangely, this works without problems on Chrome, IE although always returns false when checking for the `IsUserFavorite` property.

Comment: It says "shim available"

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I included it, still doesn't work though. :)

Comment: If the problem is that `project.IsUserFavorite` returns false, then it's unlikely that it's related to `class` at all.

Comment: The code uses `IsUser...` (uppercase `I`) while the `[class....]="project.isUser` with lowercase `i`. Just checking, I guess it's just a typo in the question.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Sorry, it's uppercase everywhere. (It wouldn't work in Chrome too if this was the issue.)
The property has the right data - I meant the if condition always returns false because (probably) it's undefined due to the async stuff. Is there a way to 'wait' for that?

Comment: What async stuff? I can't see that part in your question.

Comment: I have an array of projects (returned from an observable subscription), the part of the html shown in my question is from a *ngFor="let project of projects".

Comment: That doesn't sound async.

Comment: So what do you get if you add `<div>isFavorite: _{{project.IsUserFavorite}}_</div>`?

Comment: isFavorite: _true_ respectively false, depending on content ofc. IE although has false in every item which doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: But it shows it's not related to `class` in any way. Could it be that it's because IE is caching HTTP requests?

Comment: That's right - is it possible that it runs `getFavoriteStarClasses()` before the values are available (= always false)? No, it's not chaching.

Comment: "is it possible that it runs `getFavoriteStarClasses()` before the values are available" - not that's not possible. With `{{project.IsUserFavorite}}`, there is no `getFavoriteStarClasses()`, and yes, IE by default caches HTTP requests except it's disabled on the server http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261000/how-to-avoid-ajax-caching-in-internet-explorer-11-when-additional-query-string-p

Comment: It doesn't. We set it up that way.

Comment: Hard to tell, the problem is IMHO definitely not in the code you shared.

Comment: So strange - it's the top layer of the app... Thanks alot for your efforts!

Comment: IE11 and earlier do not support the classlist api on svg elements. Use the DOM Explorer tab of IE's dev tool to view the computed markup from the angular script generated methods or search your angular modules for the calls to classlist. The work-around is to use the class attribute instead. el.setAttribute('class',newclassvalue);

Comment: @RobParsons Basically that's what I tried :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `attr.class` with a public method that returns the classes that should be used worked. Not sure if the classList.js shim is used, I will leave it included for possible future bugs.

```
<svg [attr.class]="getFavoriteStarClasses(project)" viewBox="0 0 99.109 94.258" enable-background="new 0 0 99.109 94.258" xml:space="preserve">
    <polygon points="49.555,0 64.868,31.028 99.109,36.003 74.333,60.155 80.181,94.258 49.555,78.156 18.928,94.258 24.777,60.155 0,36.003 34.241,31.028 " />
</svg>
```