# Angular 5: hash routing makes IE fail to update view

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

In my use case (Angular 5 app embedded in a greater website), I am using hash location strategy

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})]
})
```

So my application paths are like `website.com/#/home` and `website.com/#/profile`

App works ok, but I run into one problem in Internet Explorer 11 (which I have to support): Angular change detection doesn't seem to be fully working.  Specifically, If I make a UI change to a component, navigate to another path, then return, the old view is shown. Routing works fine, but it's as if the browser cached the view and won't let Angular update the component view.

Not sure where to even start looking for a cause, let alone a fix.

Comment: Caching is in fact a real mess when it comes to IE11. But this has actually nothing to do with useHash. The browser's caching behavior is what bothers us. We ran into the same problems and had to rework the app in order to cope with IE11's caching strategy.

Comment: @DiabolicWords I bring useHash into the discussion because it seems that if I use the path routing strategy, this behavior goes away for me

Comment: @DiabolicWords how did you solve it in your case? I'm thinking the proper solution would be to set the `Cache-Control` response header, but I cannot change what the API is sending, only what Angular does in the browser.

Comment: [A related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261000/how-to-avoid-ajax-caching-in-internet-explorer-11-when-additional-query-string-p) with main approaches well summarized.

Comment: We simply attached a timestamp as a query parameter to each called URL in order to have every time a unique URL-string. That did it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After @DiabolicWords got me to understand that the issue was strictly an Internet Explorer caching issue (IE 11 caches XHR Get responses), I settled on sending a unique query param value with each XHR Get request.

I used [an HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

```
@Injectable()
export class NonceQueryParamInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor(private utility: UtilityService) {}

  public intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {

    // Checks whether this is IE, and this is a GET request
    if (this.utility.isNoCacheParamNeeded(req, navigator.userAgent)) {

      const modifiedRequest = req.clone(
          {setParams: {nocache: Date.now().toString()}}
      );

      return next.handle(modifiedRequest);

    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

I then needed to register the interceptor with the application providers

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [{ 
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
    useClass: NonceQueryParamInterceptor, multi: true 
  }]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Registering an HttpInterceptor ensured that all requests throughout the application would pass through this logic:

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example how to set the timestamp

```
private requestOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = {};
private requestUrlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

setSearchParamsTimeStamp() {
    this.requestUrlSearchParams.set('timestamp', (new Date()).getTime().toString());
    this.requestOptions.search = this.requestUrlSearchParams;
}

// an example method
public deleteData<T>(url: string, logText: string): Promise<T> {
    this.setSearchParamsTimeStamp();
    this.logger.info(this.name + logText);

    return this.http.delete(url,
        {
            headers: this.jsonHeaders,
            search: this.requestUrlSearchParams,
        })
        .toPromise()
        .then(() => null)
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your code. +1.  Note this uses the deprecated `angular/http`.  I came to the same conclusion and applied the same solution, but using the `angular/common/http` package and [its HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses)

Comment: You're welcome. ;). And thanks for the additional advice.

Comment: Of course; I've just posted the solution I came to.